# Accessing .recordFields from CKQueryNotification Swift 2

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I get the following error on didReceiveRemoteNotifications if I try to simply print this property, like:

```
let cloudKitNotification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary:   userInfo as! [String : NSObject])     
if cloudKitNotification.notificationType == .Query {
      let queryNotification = cloudKitNotification as! CKQueryNotification
      print(queryNotification.recordFields)
```

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' (0x273119c) to 'CKRecordValue' (0x2763090).

If I print the whole queryNotification, I can see the recordFields inside of it. I've spent the whole day trying to understand that. Any clues?

Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: To be clear, are you saying that the line `print(queryNotification.recordFields)` is giving the cast error?

Comment: Yes! That makes no sense for me.

Comment: It's something with a CLLocation field. I don't know why, but that's what is causing the crash. When I remove it from the subscription, everything works fine.

Comment: Create a simple test app that demonstrates the issue and file a bug report with Apple. https://bugreporter.apple.com