# Error accessing recordFields in CKQueryNotification

Tags: swift, cloudkit, cknotification

When I access the `recordFields` on a `CKQueryNotification` returned from a subscription, I get this error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' (0x1009f0630) to 'CKRecordValue' (0x1009fc050).

I process the notification like this:

```
let notification: CKNotification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: userInfo as! [String : NSObject])
```

It seems to work fine and I get a `CKQueryNotification`.

The notification recordFields prints out like:

```
<CKQueryNotification: 0x156ef2bf0; notificationType=1, notificationID=<CKNotificationID: 0x156ef41e0; UUID=ba82325d-ab9e-4805-bb26-994a1122900b>, containerIdentifier=iCloud.com.skyvalleystudio.RaceTiming, subscriptionID=Marks for 06597454-4EAD-434E-BC03-CE51D987C79F, queryNotificationReason=1, recordFields={
    location =     {
        altitude = 0;
        course = "-1";
        horizontalAccuracy = 0;
        latitude = "37.33296424";
        longitude = "-122.03937369";
        speed = "-1";
        timestamp = "484712160.263403";
        verticalAccuracy = "-1";
    };
    timeStamp = 484712160;
    user = "_2031e89e9ade8345c7d4248f3ec3a2e6";
}, recordID=<CKRecordID: 0x156ef1670; 568D257C-E849-4492-A810-CB7076FC5A22:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)>, isPublicDatabase=1>
```

So it looks like the recordFields dictionary is there and populated.
I try to access is like this:

```
let timestamp = notification.recordFields!["timeStamp"] as? NSDate
```

Then I get the error.

**UPDATE**
I filed a Apple bug report 26251611.

The CLLocation is not being decoded in the CKNotification creation is my best guess.

One possible workaround is processing the userInfo directly, but I had problems with processing the CKReference. It seems like the CKRecordValue protocol adopters should be better handled when the CKNotification is created.

**UPDATE**
Closed as duplicate of 24643471. It's still open at this time...

Comment: FYI - There was a [recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37059790/accessing-recordfields-from-ckquerynotification-swift-2) with the same basic issue. Appears to be related to the `CLLocation` field.

Comment: It does seem to be related to the CLLocation. I removed it and don't get the crash. I still am not getting the result however, so I must not understand how to parse this. Is this a standard JSON format?

Comment: What I do is get the `CKRecordID` from the notification and then query the database for the record.

Comment: I filed a bug report. I was trying to be efficient by having the data I needed come in on the notification payload rather than having another round trip. I really think their CKRecordValue typing is not working or the `CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary:)` is not completing its job.